# Proof: We have a graph where all nodes have an even degree, then the graph is 2-edge-connected.

Tags: graph-theory

Assuming we have a connected graph where all nodes have an even degree, then the graph is 2-edge-connected.

The inverse implication of the statement is wrong (I found a counterexample). But for this statement I can't find a counterexample and I think that this statement is true. How can I prove it ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you start with an even graph, and deleting an edge leaves two components: one with $k$ vertices, and one with $n-k$. What can you say about the degrees of the vertices in each component?

Comment: In both components there is exactly one node with an odd degree, the rest remains even - right?

Comment: Right. Do you see the problem with that?

Comment: Yes. It's not possible that only one vertices have an odd degree. Hence the Graph is not 1-edge-connected. But why does it follow that it is 2-edge-connected.

Comment: If a graph is connected, and you cannot disconnect the graph by removing a single edge, then it's 2-edge-connected (which means, by definition, that *at least* two edges need to be removed to disconnect it).

Comment: Actually, the problem the way you've stated it does not assume that the graph is connected, so a graph with two components would be a counterexample. I'm not sure if the problem was intended to have that as an assumption or not.

Comment: Oh i see. I am sorry. I'm assuming the graph is connected.